# Can I send arduino programs directly via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I would love to upload my arduino sketches via bluetooth, but I have no idea where to start. This is part of a bigger project I am working on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and it is fairly easy to do. see [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914170240/http://letsmakerobots.com/node/30915).

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a bunch! Next thing I'm going to do is trying to program my arduino from my android phone (there's a gcc for android!)

Comment: now that would be interesting! good luck

Comment: Link is no longer active. This is precisely why magic-link answers are not appreciated in SO community. Ghostbust, do you happen to know the general gist of the post?

Comment: @Kano, seems like someone has updated the link to point to a web archive version, to me it works at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a detailed how-to I wrote that includes instructions for Windows and a slightly more simple circuit for using the HC-05 with it's common breakout board (highly recommend getting the module on the breakout): ​http://makezine.com/projects/diy-arduino-bluetooth-programming-shield/

Comment: with HM-10 or HC-08 you can also upload arduino sketches over BLE: http://www.apploader.info/